# Bad overall video quality Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: ati, xubuntu

I have a problem with videos in Xubuntu: they suck.

I have tried both open and closed source drivers, no difference what-so-ever. By open I mean that I went on Settings>Additional drivers and selected the Xorg-open one (the default). Then I selected the second (closed-source) "flgrx", but no difference.

Videos play just fine (I tried every player, Parole, VLC, mplayer... you name it), they only have little horizontal pixel misalignment (it's like when you take a picture, cut it in 2 half, then you try to recompose the picture but you don't align it perfectly, so maybe is 5% on the right from the center, or 5% from the left of the center).

How can I have smooth video playback?

My video card:

```
1024MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series (Sapphire/PCPartner)
```

Comment: What screen resolution do you use? Which video playback software do you use? Could you be a bit more precise regarding how "suck", "play just fine", "little pixel alignment" can all mean the same thing? E.g. does it loock as if you are looking at partially the previous frame, partially the current frame? Or do you see something different? Which closed source driver did you use?

Comment: Added details..

Comment: Thanks for the update. Haven't seen this particular behaviour. With my NVidia driver, videos sometimes were split vertically. This improved when I chose Tools - Preferences - Video - X11 video output (XCB) in VLC. Another thing you might try is the latest driver from AMD.

Answer (score 0):

Install the device driver:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

then reboot.